# is it faster to create a SortedSet (of objects) and insert elements to it or create an ArrayList and sort it afterwards?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have one million lines in a file. An object is created out of each line and added to a collection. The collection has to be sorted using the custom `compareTo()` method of class.

Currently I add objects to an `ArrayList` in the order of reading, then do `Collections.sort()`.

Would it be faster to make a TreeSet?

Comment: Why won't you just try it out?

Comment: It would probably be slower, but trying out takes about three lines of code.

Comment: @FINDarkside, I am a beginner as of now so I would like to not only see it in action, but understand the theory behind it too. I am trying it out now.

Comment: arraylist has complexity of O(n) for add operation and after sorting will take time n log(n) and at the same level treeset has inbuilt custom comparator with complexity of log(n) for add and for addall() operation will give O(n log n)

Comment: Take a look at this question: [java-collections-sort-performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883821/java-collections-sort-performance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both methods are in (n log(n)) time: adding an item to an `ArrayList` has a worst case of (n), but usually is done in constant time, when the backing array is long enough. The actual sorting is in (n log(n)).

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), adding an item to a `TreeSet` is in (log n). You do this n times, so overall time complexity is (n log(n)).

However `Collections.sort` seems faster in practice.

This code snippet prints `timeArray: 380` and `timeTree: 714`.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Random;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int steps = 1000000;    // one million lines

        System.out.print("timeArray: ");
        System.out.println(timeArray(steps));
        System.out.print("timeTree: ");
        System.out.println(timeTree(steps));
    }

    private static long timeArray(int steps) {
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
            arr.add(rnd.nextInt());
        }
        Collections.sort(arr);

        return System.currentTimeMillis() - t1;
    }

    private static long timeTree(int steps) {
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        TreeSet<Integer> tree = new TreeSet<>();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
            tree.add(rnd.nextInt());
        }

        return System.currentTimeMillis() - t1;
    }
}
```