# c bead sort would like help

Tags: c, sorting

I have a large list of positive integers in an array and would like to use a bead sort but have found in to be not well documented. does anyone have the code for a bead sort?

Answer (score 2):

This page has implementations in several languages, including C:
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bead_sort

Answer (score 0):

From [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9020413/10396), comes a modification of Bead Sort that uses `O(N)` extra space instead of `O(N*k)` as in the Rosetta Code version.

```
void sort(int A[], int N)
{
    int i, j;
    int *R = calloc(N, sizeof(int));

    do for (i = j = 0; i < N; i++) 
      if (A[i]) { R[j++]++; A[i]--; }
    while (j);

    for (j = N, i = 0; i < N; i++)
      A[i] = R[--j]; // A is now sorted ascending.

    free(R);
}
```

However, it is at least 10x slower than `qsort`, and it gets worse the larger your array elements get.  I wouldn't recommend using it.