# Choosing comparing algorithms to find k max values

Tags: algorithm, comparison, quicksort

Lets say that I want to find the K max values in an array of n elements , and also return them in a sorted output.
k may be -

```
k = 30 , k = n/5 ..
```

I thought about some efficient algorithms but all I could think of was in complexity of O(nlogn). Can I do it in `O(n)? maybe with some modification of quick sort?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be solved using min-heap-based priority queue in

```
  O(NlogK) + (KlogK) time
```

If k is constant `(k=30 case)`, then complexity is equal to O(N).

If k = O(N) (`k=n/5 case)`, then  complexity is equal to O(NlogN).

Another option for constant k - [K-select algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) based on Quicksort partition with average time O(N) (while worst case O(N^2) might occur)

Comment: just for better understanding - if my input is root of n - still my complexity be O(Nlogn)?

Comment: If k~=Sqrt(N) - yes. `O(Nlog(N^1/2))=O*(N*0.5*log(N))=O(Nlog(N))`

Comment: why Shouldn't the first N be also = N^1/2? so O(N^1/2*log(N^1/2))?

Comment: For N elements, Sqrt(N) max values, with heap approach we should execute N operations, each operation might take log(Sqrt(N))

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of sorting elements in nearly O(n), if you assume that you only want to sort integers. This can be done with Algorithms like [Bucket Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) or [Radix Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), that do not rely on the comparison between two elements (which are limited to O(n*log(n))).

However note, that these algorithms also have worst-case runtimes, that might be slower than O(n*log(n)).

More information can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352313/is-there-an-on-integer-sorting-algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

No comparison based sorting algorithms can achieve a better average case complexity than O(n*lg n)

There are many papers with proofs out there but [this](http://inder-gnu.blogspot.com/2009/08/no-sorting-can-be-better-than-o-n-logn.html) site provides a nice visual example.

So unless you are given a sorted array, your best case is going to be an O(n lg n) algorithm.

There are sorts like radix and bucket, but they are not based off of comparison based sorting like your title seems to imply.