# How to sort an array efficiently

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to sort an array `[3,3,2,1,3,2,2,2,1]` to `[1,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,2]`.

I'm trying to handle it using object, using the number as key, and the occurrence as value.

```js
const sortNums = (arr) => {
  const result = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const num = result[arr[i]] || 0;
    result[arr[i]] = num + 1;
  }
  //The above will gives me { '1': 2, '2': 4, '3': 3 }

  //How to convert back to array?
}

console.log(sortNums([3,3,2,1,3,2,2,2,1]))
```

Of course I can use the `Object.entries` to map back to an array, but then the entire algorithm will be consider O(n^2) right? I'm trying to explore if it can be achieve in O(n) instead.
Or I shouldn't use object to begin with?

Comment: What's wrong with `Array.prototype.sort`…?!

Comment: @deceze he is doing a limited integer sort in O(n), similar to radix sort, he's doing the count sort thingy.

Comment: @deceze, sorting by occurance ...

Comment: @Nina Ah, that would be more obvious with an example that wouldn't end up sorted numerically…

Comment: can the numbers be negative? Are they always integers?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352313/is-there-an-on-integer-sorting-algorithm in case people are still confused.

Comment: I don't think he wants to sort by occurrence, but actually numerically - can OP maybe clarify?

Comment: maybe Timsort? search on google for some implementations examples.

Comment: @deceze: Sorry for the confusion, I've edited the example

Comment: Then, lets make things slightly interesting: as the spec guarantees ascending order for integer index properties, for certain methods, how can you know, that using an object, and certain methods for accessing its properties, won't internally use an O(n*log(n)) sort, where n is the amount of different integers in the array, worst case, length of the array? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the count for sorting the array.

```js
const sortNums = array => {
    const count = {};
    for (let v of array) count[v] = (count[v] || 0) + 1;
    return array.sort((a, b) => count[a] - count[b] || a - b);
}

console.log(sortNums([3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]));
```

An approach by using the object for sorting.

```js
const sortNums = array => {
    var count = {},
        result = {};
    for (let v of array) (count[v] = count[v] || []).push(v);
    for (let a of Object.values(count)) (result[a.length] = result[a.length] || []).push(a);
    return Object.values(result).flat(Infinity)
}

console.log(sortNums([3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]));
```

Comment: this solution is still consider O(n^2) right? With a `for` and a `sort`

Comment: not really, more O(nlogn) ... but for any other solution, you need some sorting, either an array with smaller subset of same values, or directy, as in this answer.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit on why is it a `log n` for `sort`?

Comment: According to https://blog.shovonhasan.com/time-space-complexity-of-array-sort-in-v8/ , **For arrays containing 10 or fewer elements, time complexity of .sort is O(n^2)**

Comment: right, but the target is to get a better O. mabe you have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```js
const sortNums = (arr) => {
    const result = {}

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const num = result[arr[i]] || 0;
      result[arr[i]] = num + 1;
    }

    const a = [];
    for(let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        if(result[i]) {
            a.push(...Array.from({length: result[i]}, x => i));
        }
    }
    return a;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
var curIndex = 0;
for i in result {
   arr.fill(i, curIndex, curIndex + result[i]);
   curIndex = curIndex + result[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the numbers are small non-negative integers, you can count them as you have done already, and then generate the result on the fly when someone (`Array.from()` in this example) requests for it, with a simple pair of loops:

```js
function *sortNums(array){
  let stats=[];
  for(var i of array)
    stats[i]=(stats[i]||0)+1;

  for(let i=0;i<stats.length;i++)
    while(stats[i]>0){
      stats[i]--;
      yield i;
    }
}

console.log(Array.from(sortNums([3, 3, 10, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1])).join());
```

Of course it is possible to just collect the pieces into an array, in the direct, "traditional" way:

```
let ret=[];
for(let i=0;i<stats.length;i++)
  while(stats[i]>0){
    stats[i]--;
    ret.push(i);//yield i;
  }
return ret;
```